# reltable example in Dita

Tags: dita-ot

I am using the example below to  implement the reltable. But it is giving me error ?

Please send me a working reltable example with the source files for concept/task/reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "C:\dita-ot-2.3.2\dtd\properties.dtd">
<map>
 <reltable>
  <relheader>
   <relcolspec type="concept"><topicref navtitle="Troubleshooting" href="tbs.dita" locktitle="yes"/></relcolspec>
   <relcolspec type="task"><topicref navtitle="Troubleshooting" href="taskdita.dita" locktitle="yes"/></relcolspec>
   <relcolspec type="reference"><topicref navtitle="Messages" href="msg.dita" locktitle="yes"/></relcolspec>
  </relheader>
  <relrow>
   <relcell>
   <topicref href="batsonar.dita"/>
   </relcell>
   <relcell>
   <topicref href="batcaring.dita"/>
   <topicref href="batfeeding.dita"/>
   </relcell>
   <relcell>
   <topicref href="batguano.dita"/>
   <topicref href="bathistory.dita"/>
   </relcell>
  </relrow>
 </reltable>
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked

dita -i relmapnew.ditamap -f html5 -o htmloutput

## relmapnew.ditamap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "C:\dita-ot-2.3.2\dtd\properties.dtd">
<map>
 <reltable>
  <relheader>
   <relcolspec type="concept"><topicref navtitle="Troubleshooting" href="tbs.dita" locktitle="yes"/></relcolspec>
   <relcolspec type="task"><topicref navtitle="Troubleshooting" href="taskdita.dita" locktitle="yes"/></relcolspec>
   <relcolspec type="reference"><topicref navtitle="Messages" href="msg.dita" locktitle="yes"/></relcolspec>
  </relheader>
  <relrow>
   <relcell>
   <topicref href="batsonar.dita"/>
   </relcell>
   <relcell>
   <topicref href="batcaring.dita"/>
   <topicref href="batfeeding.dita"/>
   </relcell>
   <relcell>
   <topicref href="batguano.dita"/>
   <topicref href="bathistory.dita"/>
   </relcell>
  </relrow>
 </reltable>
</map>
```

Comment: We can close this question.